# SQL Query Deduplication / Join Issue

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've been having the worst time trying to write what I feel should be a pretty simple query to deal with duplicate entries.

For context: I've created a data warehouse using Big Query and am using Stitch to pull data from Hubspot. Everything works as expected as in: I have confirmed that I have the right number of records in BigQuery.

The issue comes into how Stitch refreshes data. Instead of updating records based on object id, it appends a new row. According to their [documentation](https://www.stitchdata.com/docs/data-structure/querying-append-only-tables), the query below should work, but it doesn't for the simple reason that there exist multiple versions of a given record with the same _sdc_sequence (which I don't think should exist). There are other _sdc (stitch system fields) that I can use to help, but it's also not completely reliable for the same reasons as above.

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.*
FROM [sample-table:hubspot.companies] o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        MAX(_sdc_sequence) AS seq,
        id
    FROM [sample-table:hubspot.companies]
    GROUP BY companyid ) oo
ON o.companyid = oo.companyid
AND o._sdc_sequence = oo.seq
```

The query above returns fewer results than it should. If I run the following query, I get the right number of results, but I need the other fields besides companyid like name, description, revenue, etc.

```
SELECT o.companyid
FROM [samples_table:hubspot.companies] o
GROUP BY o.companyid
```

I was trying something like this, but it doesn't work (I'm getting the following error (Expression 'oo.properties.name.value' is not present in the GROUP BY list).

```
SELECT o.companyid,
  oo.properties.name.value,
  oo.properties.hubspot_owner_id.value,
  oo.properties.description.value
FROM [sample_table:hubspot.companies] o
LEFT JOIN [sample_table:hubspot.companies] oo
  ON o.companyid = oo.companyid
GROUP BY o.companyid
```

I'm my mind, the way that I'm thinking about this is:

1. Get list of unique records id (companyid)
2. Do a SQL "vlookup equivalent" of the raw, ungrouped company table that is sorted by insert time to get the first record that matches the id (which will be the most recent since the table is sorted)

I just don't know how to write this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using window functions:

```
#standardSQL

SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT c.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY companyid ORDER BY _sdc_sequence DESC) as seqnum 
      FROM `sample-table.hubspot.companies` c
     ) c
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I think there might have been a typo in the answer. The letter right after the parenthesis I think should be an "o", no? If I don't make the change I can't run the query. Besides that, the query works and returns the correct number of rows!

Would you mind explaining how this works?

Comment: @FelipeDaCruz . . . Or `select c.*`.

Comment: I suppose I could have googled how it works...for future reference and anyone that stumbles upon this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/rownumber-function-with-partition-by-clause-in-sql-server1

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY _sdc_sequence DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `sample-table.hubspot.companies` t
GROUP BY companyid
```

Comment: It works! Would you mind explaining how? There is one slight issue with this query though, especially compared to the answer from @Gordon Linoff in that it takes ~23s to complete vs ~6-7s for Gordon's answer.